# Filtration of path space

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $W\left(M\right)$ be the path space of $M$. An element of $W\left(M\right)$ is a continuous map $x:\left[0,\infty\right)\to M$ (with some further technical details). I've been trying to determine what the filtration is and am wondering if this is it: $$B_t=\bigcup_{s\leq t}\,\bigcup_{x\in W\left(M\right)}\{x_s^{-1}\left(B\right):B\text{ is any Borel set}\}.$$